# Java StringTokenizer Error

Tags: java, string, methods, stringtokenizer

I have a problem in one of my methods that causes me an error not allowing me to ruin the code. Here is the method.

```
    public static List<Student> getStudentList(java.io.File irStudentsFile) {
    List<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();
    Stream<String> lines;
    try {
        lines = java.nio.file.Files.lines(irStudentsFile.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    lines.forEach((Consumer<? super String>) line ->
            {
                Student student = new Student();
                StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                student.setIdStudent(Integer.valueOf(sToken.nextToken()));
                student.setName(sToken.nextToken());

                students.add(student);
            }

    );

    return students;
    }
```

I get an error on line.
    StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

The error says "StringTokenizer (java.lang.String String) in StringTokenizer cannot be appiled to (java.lang.Object String)"

How do i go about fixing this ?

Thank you

Comment: not accostumed to java8 notations, but `line` is not a `String` as the method signature is asking... you must give to `StringTokenizer` a valid String...

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is another error in your code. Find below example (it's your code in a working example)

```
public class StudenDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> list = getStudentList(new File("students.txt"));
        System.out.println("list = " + list);
    }

    public static List<Student> getStudentList(java.io.File irStudentsFile) {
        List<Student> students = new LinkedList<>();
        Stream<String> lines;
        try {
            lines = java.nio.file.Files.lines(irStudentsFile.toPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

        lines.forEach((Consumer<? super String>) line -> {
            Student student = new Student();
            StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            student.setIdStudent(Integer.valueOf(sToken.nextToken()));
            student.setName(sToken.nextToken());
            students.add(student);
        }
        );

        return students;
    }

    private static class Student {

        private Integer id;
        private String name;

        public Student() {
        }

        private void setIdStudent(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

file: students.txt

```
1 John Doe
2 Jane Doe
```

output

```
list = [Student{id=1, name=John}, Student{id=2, name=Jane}]
```